# 2013 Altima wire harness

Tags: nissan, audio, altima

My car was broken into the jack ass that did it cut the wire harness to my stock radio. Their is no way to identify each wire can some one please help me out how do I find out wat each color is for .... Thank you for your help

Comment: Nissan had 5 radio options that year. Which one did you have?

Comment: I hope they catch the jerk.

Comment: An image of the wires might help. But you say "each color' so if all the colors are unique then you can just join them, take care some may be different due to a trace color as well as the base color.